# Barman - Postgres "normal" Backups

Tags: database, postgresql, barman

I am trying to configure Barman but I can only find backups with SSH access or WAL.
Is there any other way to do automatic backups with barman that dont depend on SSH/WAL?
I dont have access to these features because its a managed db.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use barman without WAL.  If your managed db provider offers neither archive_command nor streaming, then you can't use barman.

Barman doesn't need SSH, as long as you use a streaming-only setup and use `backup_method = postgres` rather than rsync.